# Why is my Fuji X camera stuck in manual focus?

Tags: autofocus, camera-settings, manual-focus, fujifilm

I have a Fujifilm X series camera with one of the nice prime lenses, and it seems to be stuck in manual focus mode. The switch on the camera is on `S`, and I flipped it back and forth several times, but to no avail. I've tried everything, including removing and reseating the lens several times. There's no manual focus switch on the lens itself. The contacts appear clean. There's nothing in the menus, either — the quick menu has `[MF]` in yellow and can't be changed. Does my camera or lens need repair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't panic! There actually *is* an autofocus switch on the lens itself. You may have glanced over this [in the manual](http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x-t10/lens/m-focus_lens/index.html) but not paid attention. On many Fujifilm X lenses, **the entire focus ring can actually click forward or backwards**. When it's back, a distance scale is exposed and the lens is in manual focus mode. When it's forward, autofocus. You must have moved it inadvertently. Push it back again and all will be well.

Comment: For the record, I may have panicked.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had this problem on a recent holiday to Japan and I am just finding out now what the problem was. Easy when you know how.